# facet labels in plotly

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

I'd like to change the facet labels in a `plotly(_express)` plot. Here's the plot:

```py
import plotly.express as px
tips = px.data.tips()
fig = px.scatter(tips, x="total_bill", y="tip", color="smoker", facet_col="sex")
fig.show()
```

What I'd like is to remove the `sex=` from the labels.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

UPDATE: as of plotly version 4.2 in October 2019, the following usage of for_each_annotation is recommended by the docs at https://plotly.com/python/facet-plots/#customize-subplot-figure-titles

```py
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.scatter(px.data.tips(), x="total_bill", y="tip", facet_row="sex")

fig.for_each_annotation(lambda a: a.update(text=a.text.split("=")[-1]))

fig.show()
```

---

The easiest way to do this is to iterate over the annotations:

```
for a in fig.layout.annotations:
    a.text = a.text.split("=")[1]
```

Comment: Sorry, I initially answered the wrong question, I've edited it to answer the correct question :)