# remove titles plotly python

Tags: python, plotly

How can I remove the titles in the following pic?

I would like to remove top axis titles since they are redundant and too long for the pic.

[image]

This is the code I am using:

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.box(DF.melt(), y="value", facet_col="variable", boxmode="overlay", color="variable")
fig.update_yaxes(matches=None)

for i in range(len(fig["data"])):
    yaxis_name = 'yaxis' if i == 0 else f'yaxis{i + 1}'
    fig.layout[yaxis_name].showticklabels = True
    #fig.update_layout(showlegend=False)


fig.update_layout(legend = dict(bgcolor = 'white'))
fig.update_layout(plot_bgcolor='white')

fig.update_xaxes(showline=True, linewidth=2, linecolor='black')#, mirror=True)
fig.update_yaxes(showline=True, linewidth=2, linecolor='black')#, mirror=True)

fig.update_xaxes(showgrid=True, gridwidth=1, gridcolor='gray')
fig.update_yaxes(showgrid=True, gridwidth=1, gridcolor='gray')

fig.show()
```

Comment: I think the question is answered in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61693014/how-to-hide-plotly-yaxis-title-in-python).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to iterate over the labels to update the text to empty " ".
Include this in your code:

```
fig.for_each_annotation(lambda a: a.update(text=""))
```

Here is a [similar question responded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57265944/facet-labels-in-plotly)